# Virtual memory issues with MonoTouch

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

We have a hybrid Web/Native application built using MonoTouch and a UIWebView. The application stores encrypted images on disk which are then requested by the UIWebView, decrypted on the fly (via an NSUrlProtocol) and then displayed in the application.

Everything works well until we have around 27-30 images at which point we receive memory warnings and the application then crashes.

Profiling the application using Instruments we see our real memory is ~ 55MB however our virtual memory is ~ 800 MB which seems quite high. Also our physical memory seems to spike near the end.

[image: Memory profile of application]

I realise this is probably an issue with our application however we are at a loss at how to diagnose the issue. If anyone has any thoughts it would be greatly appreciated.

A couple of things we have tried:

- Monotouch profiler (only showing ~ 2mb usage)
- GC.Collect() (No change)

Thanks, 
James

Comment: Try adding "VM Tracker" to Instruments and take snapshots. You should then be able to see where most of your (dirty) memory is going. I assume CGImage, which is the most common case. Try wrapping Image operations into NSAutoReleasePool() usings and actively dispose objects you no longer need.